# remove emoji in \uXXXXX format from string using php

Tags: php, regex, emoji

I need to remove some emoji from string using \uXXXXX format.

```
$msg = "\u200b\ud83d\ude48 This is an example\nAnother line \u2199\u2199";
```

All function tried and found doesn't work. I don't know if it a problem of the function or my string...

example of function used:

```
preg_replace('/[[:^print:]]/', '', $string);
```

or:

```
function remove_emoji($string) {

// Match Emoticons
$regex_emoticons = '/[\x{1F600}-\x{1F64F}]/u';
$clear_string = preg_replace($regex_emoticons, '', $string);

// Match Miscellaneous Symbols and Pictographs
$regex_symbols = '/[\x{1F300}-\x{1F5FF}]/u';
$clear_string = preg_replace($regex_symbols, '', $clear_string);

// Match Transport And Map Symbols
$regex_transport = '/[\x{1F680}-\x{1F6FF}]/u';
$clear_string = preg_replace($regex_transport, '', $clear_string);

// Match Miscellaneous Symbols
$regex_misc = '/[\x{2600}-\x{26FF}]/u';
$clear_string = preg_replace($regex_misc, '', $clear_string);

// Match Dingbats
$regex_dingbats = '/[\x{2700}-\x{27BF}]/u';
$clear_string = preg_replace($regex_dingbats, '', $clear_string);

return $clear_string;
}
```

Tried replacing \x with \u inside function, but I get error....
Anyone can explain me why functions don't work?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your text includes actual symbols and not just `\uxxxx` strings like your example? This:

```php
$text = " This is an example. ";
print( preg_replace('/[\x{1F600}-\x{1F64F}]+/u', '', $text) );
```

should actually produce:

```
' This is an example. '
```

**Edit**: Otherwise, just match those string representations of unicode characters in your text with something like `/\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}/g` and replace them. For example:

```php
$msg = "\u200b\ud83d\ude48 This is an example\nAnother line \u2199\u2199";
print( preg_replace('/\\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}/', '', $msg) );
```

Output:

```
" This is an example
Another line "
```

Comment: Hi, my text in example is what i get from a var_dump

Comment: Thanks for support, I tried '/\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}/' (without g cause i get error) it seems to work but all '\' are not removed

Comment: `g` is just the global match flag, you don't need it for `preg_replace()`. You'll probably have to escape the `\u` further for your use case - either `\\\u` or `\\\\u`.